# Calculate the size of content are with jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, css

When designing web page on mobile, I usually create the header and footer, as different mobile have different size of screen, I want to show an image in full screen mode excluding the height of header and footer, how can I calculate the actual size of the content?

Comment: if the html is properly contained, there are 2 jquery functions to get height => .innerHeight http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/ and .outerHeight http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/ Oh, almost forgot about .height() http://api.jquery.com/Height/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your elements all have a proper height. Example sometimes floating divs lose their height if not used properly. Use any of the height functions from my comment above and it should be good for this purpose.